# is sitemap.xml loaded with page or by robots only?

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, sitemap, robots.txt

I want to know if sitemaps are loaded by browsers or only search engines use them for crawling. 
I have dynamic page with multiple sections with dynamic content and generating this add extra mysql query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitemaps can be loaded by a browser, if a visitor opens their url, but they are intended for crawlers, and browsers won't go looking for them.

I don't understand how that would relate to MySQL.